# Store contents with rest proxy giving incorrect count

Tags: rest, extjs, store

ExtJS 5.1.x, with several stores using rest proxy.

Here is an example:

```
Ext.define('cardioCatalogQT.store.TestResults', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Store',
    alias: 'store.TestResults',
    config:{
        fields: [
            {name: 'attribute', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'sid', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value_s', type: 'string'},
            {name: 'value_d', type: 'string'}
        ],
        model: 'cardioCatalogQT.model.TestResult',
        storeId: 'TestResults',
        autoLoad: true,
        pageSize: undefined,
        proxy: {
            url: 'http://127.0.0.1:5000/remote_results_get',
            type: 'rest',
            reader: {
                type: 'json',
                rootProperty: 'results'
            }
        }
    }
});
```

This store gets populated when certain things happen in the API. After the store is populated, I need to do some basic things, like count the number of distinct instances of an attribute, say `sid`, which I do as follows:

```
test_store =  Ext.getStore('TestResults');
n = test_store.collect('sid').length);
```

The problem is that I have to refresh the browser to get the correct value of 'n,' otherwise, the count is not right. I am doing a `test_store.load()` and indeed, the request is being sent to the server after the `.load()` is issued.

I am directly querying the backend database to see what data are there in the table and to get a count to compare to the value given by `test_store.collect('sid').length);`. The strange thing is that I am also printing out the store object in the debugger, and the expected records (when compared to the content in the database table) are displayed under `data.items` array, but the value given by `test_store.collect('sid').length` is not right.

This is all done sequentially in a success callback. I am wondering if there is some sort of asynchronous behavior giving me the inconsistent results between what is is the store and the count on the content of the store?

I tested this with another store that uses the rest proxy and it has the same behavior. On the other hand, using the localStorage proxy gives the correct count consistent with the store records/model instances.

Here is the relevant code in question, an Ajax request fires off and does its thing correctly, and hit this success callback. There really isn't very much interesting going on... the problem section is after the `console.log('TEST STORE HERE');` where I get the store, print the contents of the store, load/sync then print the store (which works just fine) and then finally print the length of uniquely grouped items by the `sid` attribute (which is what is not working):

```
success: function(response) {
            json = Ext.decode(response.responseText);

            if(json !== null &&  typeof (json) !==  'undefined'){

                for (i = 0, max = json.items.length; i < max; i += 1) {

                    if (print_all) {
                        records.push({
                            sid: json.items[i].sid,
                            attribute: json.items[i].attribute,
                            string: json.items[i].value_s,
                            number: json.items[i].value_d
                        });
                    }
                    else {

                        records.push({
                            sid: json.items[i].sid
                        })
                    }

                }

                //update store with data
                store.add(records);
                store.sync();

                // only add to store if adding to search grid
                if (!print_all) {
                    source.add({
                        key: payload.key,
                        type: payload.type,
                        description: payload.description,
                        criteria: payload.criteria,
                        atom: payload.atom,
                        n: store.collect('sid').length // get length of array for unique sids

                    });
                    source.sync();
                }

                console.log('TEST STORE HERE');
                test_store = Ext.getStore('TestResults');
                test_store.load();
                test_store.sync();
                console.log(test_store);
                console.log(test_store.collect('sid').length)
            }

            // update grid store content
            Ext.StoreMgr.get('Payload').load();
            Ext.ComponentQuery.query('#searchGrid')[0].getStore().load();

        }
```

For completeness, here is the data.items array output `items:Array[2886]`
which is equivalent count of unique items grouped by the attribute `sid` and finally the output of `console.log(test_store.collect('sid').length)`, which gives the value from the PREVIOUS run of this: `3114`...

Comment: What do you mean by "doesn;t work"? When you call load, does it make the request to the server?

Comment: Yes, the request IS going to the server. I just verified it. So, this begs the question: if it is being sent to the server then why are stale data being served? Refreshing the browser does give the expected results.

Comment: How are you verifying that the results are stale? Does the store fire the load event? If so, what records are passed back as part of that event. Is the store the correct instance?

Unless you post a working sample you'll need to do some debugging to provide more information.

Comment: I am editing the original question for more specificity.

Comment: It would be better off if you posted the relevant code.

Comment: see above for more specificity on the chunk of code

Comment: Loading is asynchronous, you're not waiting for the store to load. Listen to the load event.

Comment: That was it (I had a feeling there was some async behavior going on). Please post your response as an answer and I will accept it. Thanks!